# How to translate Symfony2 Exception

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml

I'm using yml format to translate my web app but I've one problem.

What I would like to do:

```
#exception.en.yml
exception.bad: 'Bad credentials'
```

What I know is possible to do:

```
#exception.en.yml
'Bad credentials': 'Bad credentials'
```

Is this the only method to translate the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply put in the translator and remember to add the `trans` statement on the messagge error dump in the Twig template.

Here an xliff example:

```
    messages.en.xlf

        <trans-unit id="1">
            <source>User account is disabled.</source>
            <target>Account disabled or waiting for confirm</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="2">
            <source>Bad credentials</source>
            <target>Wrong username or password</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

and in the template

```
{# src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig #}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Check [this doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-non-active-users) for exclude non active users

hope this help

Comment: Exactly how I was thinking, very useful!