# Symfony2: Override exception messages in form login

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've built a login form rendered by this controller action:

```
public function loginAction() {
    $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    return $this->render('SecurityLoginBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
                'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
                'error' => $helper->getLastAuthenticationError(),
    ));
}
```

If the user does not provide a valid email/password "getLastAuthenticationError()" throws a "BadCredentialsException"; if the user is disabled a "DisabledException" is thrown. Both exception objects have a "message" property but I'd like to change the labels. How do I do that?

An ugly workaround would be to read those messages in my Twig template and replace them with my wording but is there a better way? Like checking the class of the "*error*" parameter in Twig. Unfortunately

```
get_class($helper->getLastAuthenticationError())
```

didn't work - it returns "*Security\LoginBundle\Controller\LoginController*".

Thanks!

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574513/how-to-translate-symfony2-exception/26577327#26577327

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I solved it when i see

```
class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AuthenticationAuthenticationUtils
```

getLastAuthenticationError has default parameter $clearSession =true

So you can handle error and after clear session

```
    $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    $error = $helper->getLastAuthenticationError();
```

You can also if error is an instance of some Exception throw an Exception with your custom message

```
    if ($error instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
         throw \Exception('Your Custom exception'); 
    }
```

Add try catch if you want and create new var $error with your custom message.
and after return content message because it's an exception :

```
    return $this->render('SecurityLoginBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
            'error' => $error ? $error->getMessage() : null,
    ));
```